# EF6 POCO Unable to cast object of type HashSet in a 1..* Relationship

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6, poco

I am trying to use Entity Framework 6 and POCOs against an existing database with the following structure:

> **Departments**
>   DepartmentID        UNIQUEIDENTIFIER      NOT NULL *PK*
>   SortOrder               INT                                  NULL
>   Image                     IMAGE                            NULL
>   Status                     BIT                                  NULL
>   LastUpdated           DATETIME                      NOT NULL
>   UpdatedBy             NVARCHAR(10)              NULL
>   Approved                BIT                                  NOT NULL
>   ApprovedBy            NVARCHAR(10)             NULL
>   ApprovedDate         DATETIME                     NULL
>   ParentDepartment   UNIQUEIDENTIFIER     NULL
>
> **DepartmentDescriptions**
>        DepartmentID   UNIQUEIDENTIFIER   NOT NULL *PK, FK*
>   LocaleID           INT                                NOT NULL *PK, FK*
>        Description       NVARCHAR(50)           NOT NULL
>
> **Locales**
>   LocaleID           INT                       NOT NULL *PK*
>   ShortString       NVARCHAR(10)   NOT NULL
>   Description       NVARCHAR(50)   NOT NULL
>   Status               BIT                        NOT NULL

My classes are:

```
public class Department
{
    [Key]
    public Guid DepartmentID { get; set; }
    public Int32? SortOrder { get; set; }
    public Byte[] Image { get; set; }
    public Boolean Status { get; set; }
    public DateTime LastUpdated { get; set; }
    public String UpdatedBy { get; set; }
    public Boolean Approved { get; set; }
    public String ApprovedBy { get; set; }
    public DateTime ApprovedDate { get; set; }
    public Guid? ParentDepartment { get; set; }

    // Navigation Properties
    public virtual ICollection<DepartmentDescription> DepartmentDescriptions { get; set; }

    public Department()
    {
        DepartmentDescriptions = new HashSet<DepartmentDescription>();
    }

}


public class DepartmentDescription
{
    [Key]
    public Guid DepartmentID { get; set; }
    public Int32 LocaleID { get; set; }
    public String Description { get; set; }

    // Navigation Properties
    [ForeignKey("DepartmentID"), Required] 
    public virtual Department Department { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("LocaleID"), Required]
    public virtual Locale Locale { get; set; }

}

public class Locale
{
    [Key]
    public Int32 LocaleID { get; set; }
    public String ShortString { get; set; }
    public String Description { get; set; }
    public Boolean Status { get; set; }

    // Navigation Properties
    public virtual ICollection<DepartmentDescription> DepartmentDescriptions { get; set; }

    public Locale()
    {
        DepartmentDescriptions = new HashSet<DepartmentDescription>();
    }
}
```

When I try to add a new Department to the context I get:

```
*Unable to cast object of type 'System.Collections.Generic.HashSet`1[DepartmentDescription]' to type 'DepartmentDescription'.*
```

The code to add a new department (paraphrased) is:

```
Department _department = new Department
    {
        DepartmentID = new Guid("aed99956-c3e1-44a7-b09a-00169f64bdff"),
        Status = true, 
        SortOrder = 320, 
        Image = null, 
        Approved = true, 
        ApprovedBy = "Import", 
        ApprovedDate = Convert.ToDateTime("11/22/2016 3:40:50PM"), 
        LastUpdated = Convert.ToDateTime("11/22/2016 3:40:50PM"), 
        UpdatedBy = Import
    };  

DepartmentDescription _description = new DepartmentDescription 
    {
        DepartmentID = new Guid("aed99956-c3e1-44a7-b09a-00169f64bdff"),
        LocaleID = 1033, 
        Description = "Department Description"
    };

_department.DepartmentDescriptions.Add(_description);
context.Departments.Add(_department);
```

I'm sure I'm doing something that will deserve a facepalm, but I've been staring at this too long to see what I'm missing. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You're trying to add a HashSet to a HashSet.

Comment: To show what @GertArnold is talking about, can you add the code in question. Specifically the part where you are trying to add a new `Department`.

Comment: Added the code to add a new Department

Comment: *paraphrased* -- The error suggests that in reality, in `_department.DepartmentDescriptions.Add(_description);`, `_description` is a HashSet.

Comment: Agreed. That's where I'm confused. DepartmentDescriptions is a HashSet of DepartmentDescription objects but _description is a single DepartmentDescription. The way I'm interpreting the error, EF is expecting a single description and I'm passing it a HashSet (or a List because I've tried that too) :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The DepartmentDescriptions table has a composite primary key which isn't represented by the DepartmentDescription class. As a result, the DbContext is trying to do its magical ORM stuff with POCOs that don't map to the database schema properly.

Using DataAnnotations, the DepartmentDescription class should look like this:

```
public class DepartmentDescription
{
   [Key]
   [Column(Order = 1)]
   public Guid DepartmentID { get; set; }
   [Key]
   [Column(Order = 2)]
   public Int32 LocaleID { get; set; }
   public String Description { get; set; }

   // Navigation Properties
   [ForeignKey("DepartmentID"), Required]
   public virtual Department Department { get; set; }

   [ForeignKey("LocaleID"), Required]
   public virtual Locale Locale { get; set; }

}
```

Comment: Well I was right about one thing...Facepalm :-)  Thank you so much colinsmith1!